# Shell commands generated by jq do not run correctly

Tags: json, bash, postgresql, shell

I'm trying to execute a postgres command in a bash script, but I do not know why it does not work.

The problem is that I need to read the data from a JSON file. To do this I use the jq library and I create the sentence, but psql only gives mistakes.

file.json

```
{
  "databases": [
    "db1",
    "db2"
  ],
  "logins": [
    {
      "username": "user1",
      "password": "pwd1"
    },
    {
      "username": "user2",
      "password": "pwd2"
    }
  ],
  "rights": [
    {
      "username": "user1",
      "database": "db1",
      "grant": "ALL PRIVILEGES"
    },
    {
      "username": "user2",
      "database": "db2",
      "grant": "ALL PRIVILEGES"
    }
  ]
}
```

init.sh

```sh
# rights

mapfile -t arr < <(jq -M -r '.rights[] | "psql -d 'template1' -U 'postgres' -c GRANT \"" +  .grant + "\" ON DATABASE \"" + .database + "\" TO \"" + .username + "\";"' $CONFIG_PATH)

for a in "${arr[@]}"; $a; done
```

error

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument ""ALL" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "PRIVILEGES"" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "ON" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "DATABASE" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument ""db1"" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "TO" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument ""user1";" ignored
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: GRANT
             ^
```

I've tried it in different ways, but they all fail :(

Does anyone know how to do? Many thanks!

Comment: the entire query should be quoted so it can be passed as one parameter to `-c`.

Comment: Could also tell jq to generate shell-escaped output and run the result *as a script*

Comment: Immediately, though, this is running into the misconceptions addressed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: This would be a lot easier in a different language, one that has JSON and PostgreSQL libraries already.

Comment: Certainly *safer*. Since someone who can run arbitrary code as an administrator in PostgreSQL can tell the database server to write arbitrary files and run arbitrary executables (within the limits of its own permissions), using bash to generate SQL is generally a bad idea.

Comment: (s/using bash/using string concatenation/; letting jq do the concatenation doesn't address that problem, as it knows how to escape things to be shell-safe, but not how to be sql-safe, and Doing It Right requires both).

Comment: The problem is that I have a docker image with postgres and I need to create the users, databases and rights, when the I start the image. To do this I read the json and create them. Maybe there is another better way.

Comment: If you trust the source of your JSON files, the current proposed answer is probably good enough. If it *isn't*, please fill me in on what you'd like to see changed (since leaving all answers unaccepted means leaving the question marked as still needing more answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code had serious security vulnerabilties. As adjusted below, we're vulnerable only to SQL injection, no longer to shell injection; and are no longer trying to run *data* as code in a shell:

```
sql=$(jq -r '
  .rights[] |
  "GRANT \"\(.grant)\" ON DATABASE \"\(.database)\" TO \"\(.username)\";"' \
  <"$config_path"
)
psql -d template1 -U postgres -c "$sql"
```

If you **really** want to use `jq` to generate shell commands, you can do that, but to do so safely requires using using the jq primitive `@sh`; and to then parse the result as code rather than data requires `eval`:

```
eval "$(jq -r '
  .rights[] |
  [ "psql", "-d", "template1", "-U", "postgres",
    "-c", "GRANT \"\(.grant)\" ON DATABASE \"\(.database)\" TO \"\(.username)\";"
  ] | @sh' \
  <"$config_path"
)"
```